# How to apply watermark using MIP SDK (Microsoft Information protection)

Tags: c#, watermark, microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

I am trying to implement Content Marking using MIP SDK version 1.5

As per information from below URL, it is possible to implement content marking. I have tried but couldn't. I want to implement applying content marking(watermark) in word/pdf document while applying label. I have set label and encryption in protection.office.com.

Any help would be great.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-and/microsoft-information-protection-sdk-1-5-now-available/ba-p/1180707

Comment: You are going to need to show the code that you have tried and explain what the failure you are seeing is.  This site responds to questions with code much better than open ended questions like yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIP SDK doesn't support direct content marking. When you apply a label via the SDK that applies content marking, instead of marking the document, it applies a property called ContentBits. This property informs Office or the AIP Client that they should apply the content marking when the document is opened.

We don't have plans at the moment to support direct content marking.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/concept-mip-metadata#microsoft-information-protection-sdk-metadata

Comment: Thank you. I get it. There is an access error I am getting though it works good while creating profile and engine. But while setting label, throws error as "AccessDeniedException. The service didn't accept the auth token".  Appreciate your help..
Line: var result = Task.Run(async () => await handler.CommitAsync(options.OutputName)).Result;

Comment: This sounds auth related. You'll need to validate that the audience in your  token is for the resource you're sending it to. The SDK uses two service endpoints. If you don't use the resource provided to the AuthDelegate  when fetching the token, you'll send the wrong token to the service endpoint.